# Sharepoint 2010 Auditing - audit document approval

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-approval, auditing

We have new requirement in one of our projects to keep track of users who approved document in library.

We are aware that there is auditing solution built-in in SharePoint, but I couldn't find information regarding document approval. Does built-in audit keep track of users who approve or reject documents in library?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Content Modification report should log the publishing/approval records as "This report shows all events that modified content in this site." Publishing and approval modify the item metadata so it should be captured.